# Explaining information on Contour

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I wish to compute the following line integral $$\int_{C}(x-iy)dz$$ where $z(t)=(e^t- 1,t)$, $t \in [0,2]$

$dz = dx + idy = (e^t - 1 + i)dt$
We then have $\int_{C}(e^{t} - 1 - it)(e^t - 1 + i)dt$

I'm confused on what information we have about our contour $C$. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Take the limit of the integration as $0$ to $2$..which comes from contour $C$...

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^2(e^{t} - 1 - it)(e^t - 1 + i)\,dt$$

$$=\int_0^2(e^t-1)^2+t+i[e^t-1-te^t+t]\,dt$$

$$=\left[\frac{e^{2t}}{2}-2e^t+t+\frac{t^2}{2}+i\{e^t-t-te^t+t+\frac{t^2}{2}\}\right]_0^2$$

Comment: Why down vote ??? Write your reason before downvoting...